# SQL - query and replace column value with another value extracted from the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID  |  NAME  | ID_PREVIOUS  | ID_FOLLOWING |   RANDOM_USELESS_DATA
----+--------+--------------+--------------+---------------------
1   | AB2-F  |     NULL     |     2        |      bla bla bla
2   | PP-01  |      1       |     3        |      ffwfwqafrwf
3   | 10J6U  |      2       |     7        |      ihjfoiwhfo
7   | F-1-R  |      3       |   NULL       |      fdojshflos
```

This table represent a kind of graph. Every line is a node with its id, its name, the id of the previous and following node and some other data that is not useful for the question. Notice that the adiacent nodes could be null, meaning that there is only one connection for the specific node.

What I cannot do is to make a query that substitutes all the IDs with the corresponding node name. I need to represent the "graph" with the names but i don't know how to do. My ideal result would be:

```
NAME  |  NAME_PREVIOUS |   NAME_FOLLOWING
------+----------------+------------------
AB2-F |    NULL        |  PP-01
PP-01 |    AB2-F       |  10J6U
10J6U |    PP-01       |  F-1-R
F-1-R |    10J6U       |  NULL
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'd like to keep it generic, since i have to extract from an access db and insert into a postgre/mysql for future use

Comment: "*generic*" is just another way of say "*equally slow on all platforms*" (btw: it's Postgres not Postgre)

Comment: performances are not mandatory, it's gonna be run few of times and with a small db (~20k lines). And the 's' slipped off the keyboard :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.NAME, 
TP.NAME AS NAME_PREVIOUS,
TF.NAME AS NAME_FOLLOWING
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS TP TP.ID = T.ID_PREVIOUS 
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS TF TF.ID = T.ID_FOLLOWING
```

That's general SQL that should work for the most DBMS I suppose, however as I know Access query builder for some reasons also adds bracket in FROM clause like this:

```
SELECT T.NAME, 
TP.NAME AS NAME_PREVIOUS,
TF.NAME AS NAME_FOLLOWING
FROM (YOUR_TABLE AS T
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS TP TP.ID = T.ID_PREVIOUS) 
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS TF TF.ID = T.ID_FOLLOWING
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single level of "previous/following" you can get away with a self-join

```
select nd.name, 
       pr.name as name_previous,
       nx.name as name_following
from nodes nd 
  left join nodes pr on nd.id_previous = pr.id
  left join nodes nx on nd.id_following = nx.id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/21b46/2

If you have multiple levels you need a recursive query (which is not supported by MS-Access or MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.NAME as NAME, b.NAME as NAME_PREVIOUS, c.NAME as NAME_FOLLOWING
FROM GRAPH_TABLE a LEFT JOIN GRAPH_TABLE b on a.ID_PREVIOUS=b.ID
LEFT JOIN GRAPH_TABLE c on a.ID_FOLLOWING=c.ID.
```

You can check the example here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c73c4/3

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table T
SET T.NAME_PREVIOUS = (SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ID = T.ID_PREVIOUS),
T.NAME_FOLLOWING = (SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ID = T.ID_FOLLOWING);
```

Comment: I do not want to update the table, just swap some values in the result of the query.